# Cascade Classifier invariant to different colored objects?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cascade-classifier

So recently I have been trying to detect objects by training my own Cascade Classifier. Specifically, I wish to be able to detect drones in the sky. However, my dataset only includes drones of specific colors and I want it to detect drones of all colors.

I thought about maybe running Edge Detection on my training images and using those images to train the Classifier. Is this a good approach? Any suggestions on how to train a Cascade Classifier to be color invariant?

Comment: Have you tried using grayscale?

Comment: @NielsHenkens Yes I'm running on grayscale images, the classifier is having problems recognizing drones of certain shades of gray.